# Return .NET Core API image (stored under wwwroot directory) link to client

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, ionic4

My .NET Core API stores uploaded images under */wwwroot/uploads/images/*

I need to show those images in my Ionic App so I would need a URL pointing to the images like: *http://hostname:5000/uploads/images/image.png*, so I can do something in my App like:

*< img src="http://hostname:5000/uploads/images/image.png" />*

The fact is that when I put this URL in my browser it returns a 404 (not found) error.

**Which would be the right URL and how do I return it from the API?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .net core you have to enable static files. You can do so by adding UseStaticFiles() to the application builder in your Configure method of your Startup class.

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I have already enabled it but the link _http://hostname:port/uploads/images/image_ keeps returning a 404 error for a file located under _/wwwroot/uploads/images/_

Comment: Can you try `app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
 FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
  Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "uploads", "images")),
 RequestPath = "/MyImages"
});`  and request it like `http://hostname:5000/MyImages/image.png`